# golang tar.Read truncating data

Tags: go, tar

I'm having a problem extracting a tar archive using golang tar library. The header reads the correct size and my buffer is the same size, but when i call tar.Read I do not get all of the data in my buffer. I cant figure out why this is happening.

The tarball contains up to 4 files, and it seems to be the thermostat.csv file that's getting cut off.

When I use bash to extract the files they come out clean, so i'm pretty sure nothing is wrong with the tarball.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "compress/gzip"
    "os"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var filename string
    //untar each file
    filename = "/tmp/6yHYKND3t0"
    f,err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic("cant open file")
    }
    defer f.Close()
    gzf,err := gzip.NewReader(f)
    check(err)
    tarReader := tar.NewReader(gzf)
    for {
        header,err := tarReader.Next()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        check(err)
        name := header.Name
        switch header.Typeflag {
            case tar.TypeDir:
                os.Mkdir("/tmp/enTest/"+name,0755)
            case tar.TypeReg:
                data := make([]byte,header.Size)
                fmt.Printf("Header Size: %d\n",header.Size)
                l,err := tarReader.Read(data)
                fmt.Printf("Length of buffer: %d\n", len(data))
                fmt.Printf("Read from tar.Read: %d\n",l)
                check(err)
                outputFile := "/tmp/enTest/"+name
                fmt.Println("Writing file to :",outputFile)
                ioutil.WriteFile(outputFile,data,0755)
            default:
                fmt.Println("Unknown type %c %s\n",header.Typeflag,name)
                panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

outputs the following:

```
Header Size: 47537370
Length of buffer: 47537370
Read from tar.Read: 31744
Writing file to : /tmp/enTest/d2af74605ac45cf6b19c068d2d8e2710/thermostats.csv
Header Size: 34038106
Length of buffer: 34038106
Read from tar.Read: 7168
Writing file to : /tmp/enTest/d2af74605ac45cf6b19c068d2d8e2710/energy-monitors.csv
Header Size: 72965
Length of buffer: 72965
Read from tar.Read: 14336
Writing file to : /tmp/enTest/d2af74605ac45cf6b19c068d2d8e2710/lights.csv
Header Size: 7158655
Length of buffer: 7158655
Read from tar.Read: 6144
Writing file to : /tmp/enTest/d2af74605ac45cf6b19c068d2d8e2710/remote-sensors.csv
Header Size: 1732617
Length of buffer: 1732617
Read from tar.Read: 23040
Writing file to : /tmp/enTest/d2af74605ac45cf6b19c068d2d8e2710/hvac-controllers.cs
```

v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [io.Reader documentation](https://godoc.org/io#Reader) says:

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. ... If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.

Read is not guaranteed to fill the data argument. Use [io.ReadFull](https://godoc.org/io#ReadFull) to fill the buffer.

```
l,err := io.ReadFull(tarReader, data)
```

Comment: Unbelievable. Is that documented somewhere? I didn't see anything about it.

Comment: It’s in the [`Read` Documentation](https://godoc.org/io#Reader), but also how the `read` syscall work, as well as similar functions in most languages.

Comment: @MuffinTop "It’s documented, but the point is easy to miss." No it is not. io.Reader is one of _the_ _fundamental_ interfaces in Go, it is even covered in the Tour of Go (https://tour.golang.org/methods/21) and, as usual, the documentation is meant to be read in full.